# How do I restart a thread if its duration is longer than 10 seconds?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

How in the main thread can I track the duration of the function write_file()?
Task: create a condition, if the execution time of the function is more than 10 seconds, then it is necessary to restart the function.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def write_file(file: str):
    f = open(file, 'w')
    for item in range(0, 1500000):
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
    f.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_files = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']
    with Pool(3) as p:
        p.map(write_file, list_files)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found attempt to amend Pool to be overcomplicated here.
The Pool class let workers to be alive untill the whole working queue is done and thus has complex mechanism to control it.

Instead, if you have not very stict requirenments on 10 second, you can use the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
pdict = {}
for fname in list_files:
    p = Process(target = write_file, args = (fname,))
    pdict[fname] = p
    p.start()
while pdict:
    to_del = []
    time.sleep(10)
    for pname in pdict:
        if pdict[pname].exitcode == None or pdict[pname].is_alive():
            pdict[pname].terminate() #killing old; that should also release file resource
            pdict[pname] = Process(target = write_file, args = (pname,))
            pdict[pname].start() #simply creating new and starting
        else:
            to_del.append(pname)
    for pname in to_del:
        del pdict[pname]
```

Comment: Please show the error details. I've launched this and it works without any error on python 3.6.